# Find bottom of Excel worksheet in VBA Copy Images

Tags: vba, image, excel, copy-paste

I would like to move a photo to the bottom of cell but it does not work please help me?

`.Top = Target.Top -> .Bottom = Target.Bottom`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, [A:A]) Is Nothing Or Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next
    Target(, 2).Worksheet.Shapes(Target.Address).Delete
    On Error GoTo Thoat

    Copy_Images Target.Value

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
    With Selection
        .Name = Target.Address
        .Top = Target.Top
        .Left = Target(, 2).Left
        .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
        .ShapeRange.Height = Target.Height
        .ShapeRange.Width = Target(, 2).Width
    End With
Thoat:
    Target.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub

Private Sub Copy_Images(imageName As String)
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each sh In Sheets(2).Shapes
        If sh.Name = imageName Then
            sh.Copy
            'Sheets(1).Pictures.Paste
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

---

I want to Resize Column to Fit Picture please help me:

```
With Selection
     .Name = Target.Address
     .Top = Target.Top
     .Left = Target(, 2).Left
     .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
     '.ShapeRange.Height = Target.Height
     '.ShapeRange.Width = Target(, 2).Width
End With
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Could you expand on "it doesn't work"?  What have you tried? The line with `Paste` is commented-out; could that be your problem?!  Be sure to check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There's no `Bottom` property, so you need something like

```
.Top = Target.Top + Target.Height
```